# Add a Keyboard Shortcut to Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox Extension. I added a new item to the "Tools" Menu to open my extension, but I would like to add a keyboard shortcut to open my extension (something like 'control + alt + x').

Comment: I've found it by myself

     <keyset id="mainKeyset">    
        <key id="key_convert" key="x" modifiers="accel alt" oncommand="OpenMyAddOn()"/>  
     </keyset>

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Keyboard_Shortcuts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found it by myself

```
<keyset id="mainKeyset"> <key id="key_convert" key="x" modifiers="accel alt" oncommand="OpenMyAddOn()"/> </keyset>
```

Answer (score 8):

The `commands` key is a good way to do this these days; for instance to toggle the main extension pop up (known as the `browser_action`), use the following in `manifest.json`:

```json
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
    }
  }
}
```

This also exposes an entry in the **Add-ons Manager -> Manage Extension Shortcuts** settings area where the user can re-map the keyboard shortcut.

Read more on the documentation page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands

Comment: This is the true answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add shortcut key to Firefox own menu to execute addon action, then you need to edit
`extension\content\firebug\firefox\browserMenu.js`
and add **accesskey**:

```
    // Firefox page context menu
    $menupopupOverlay(doc, $(doc, "contentAreaContextMenu"), [
        $menuseparator(doc),
        $menuitem(doc,{
            id: "menu_ext",
            ....
            accesskey: "s"
        })
    ]);
```